# Using the http.get response data within the service in Angular 2. We are getting the undefined object error after the subscribe method scope

Tags: angular2-services

```
import {Injectable,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

export class User {
  constructor(
  public username: string,
  public password: string) { }
}

var users_static = [
new User('admin@admin.com','admin'),
new User('user@gmail.com','user')
];

@Injectable()
export class UserAuthentication  {
usersLDAP:User[];

constructor(
private _router: Router,private http:Http){

}

getUsers(){
  return this.http.get('api/Users.json')
  .map((res) =>{return res.json()})
 }

private handleError(error: any) {
console.log('An error occurred', error);
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

login(user:User){
 this.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.usersLDAP =data,()=>{},      
 ()=>console.log(this.usersLDAP));
 console.log(this.usersLDAP);
```

The second console.log gives me a undefined object error
     return false;

```
}
```

Kindly help me in this.basically I want to use the this.userLDAP object to login. I understand the userLDAP object is going out of scope after the http request 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is that the second `console.log()` is executed **before** the `GET-Request` returns. Therefore `usersLDAP` is undefined.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133128/how-to-store-data-from-firebaselistobservable-to-an-array/42134007#42134007). I think it describes a similar problem