# How to use data that is returned by a service in a sequential manner in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-services

I am a beginner in Angular2 and have some doubts. I have  data coming from a RESTful service into my component in a method in which I am calling service method. The problem is that when I try to use that data, that particular code is getting executed before the data is returned, hence I cannot make use of that data. 
Here is my Component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent {

login:loginJson;
errorMessage: string;

constructor(private _loginService: LoginService) { };

loginSubmit(email: string, password: string) {

this._loginService.setLoginUrl(email, password);

 this._loginService.getLoginFlag().subscribe(
   login => this.login = login,
   error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
 );

 console.log(this.login.sessionId);// Here is the problem where I cannot use 
                                      the sessionId
 }     
}
}
```

Here is my service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {


constructor(private _http: Http) { };
_loginUrl: string = "";

setLoginUrl(email: string, password: string): void {

    this._loginUrl = "http://localhost:8081/hawkeye/webapi/user/login?
 emailId=" + email + "&password=" + password;
}

getLoginFlag(): Observable<loginJson> {

    return this._http.get(this._loginUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <loginJson>response.json())
        .do(data => console.log("All:" + 
JSON.stringify(data))).catch(this.handleError);

}


private handleError(error: Response) {

    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
}

}
```

Here is my interface named loginJson:

```
export interface loginJson {

sessionId: string;
}
```

Problem is that I cannot use the sessionId since it is being printed in the console before I get the data from the backend. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using promises? Or call a function from within your subscribe method to do that work.

Comment: Put your `console.log` inside the `subscribe()` body.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. I am trying to call a function in the subscribed method but I am getting an error stating "Declaration or statement expected.) " Am I missing something?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42134007/2908576) has more information about using data returned from async callbacks.

Comment: Here is the edit :  loginSubmit(email: string, password: string) {

     this._loginService.setLoginUrl(email, password);

     this._loginService.getLoginFlag().subscribe(

       login => this.login = login,
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
       () => {
         console.log(this.login.sessionId);
        } 
      ); 
     }  //Getting error as Declaration or statement expected.). What am I missing